# simple but (seemingly?) tricky recurrence

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relation

I'm [cross-posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2517611/simple-but-seemingly-tricky-recurrence) from math stack exchange after receiving no answers there.

I came across the following very simple recurrence-style expression but am having trouble solving it:
$$T(2n) \in \theta(T(n) \log(T(n)))$$
for sufficiently large $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

My first thought was to take the logarithm of both sides and apply the Master Theorem but the "$f(n)$" term unfortunately is not in the right form. Repeated expanding quickly yields a mess. Wolfram Alpha was no use.

Plugging in $T(n) = n^a$ makes the left side grow too slowly so $T$ must grow faster than any polynomial. But plugging in $T(n) = \exp(\log(n)^b)$, $b>1$, causes the left side to grow too fast so $T$ must grow more slowly. So it seems $T$ is super-polynomial but *barely*.

What approaches are viable for such an equation?

Comment: It seems you have figured out a close upper bound, but perhaps you should make it explicit in the question that you want a big-theta characterization.

Comment: T(n) = 2 is a solution :)

Comment: “T(n) = n^a makes the left side grow too slowly”. I can’t see that. I think it will grow too fast if a > 1.

Comment: Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: @D.W. I cross posted because I have seen it done before and it was not badly received. I originally posted to math SE over a month ago and thought the question was relevant to this site as well. I apologize if it's bad etiquette. Should I delete the math SE question, as it is the one that has no answers?

Comment: Yes.  If you post on the wrong site, you should delete on the original site before posting on a new site. You should also take into account the comments you got on the other site and use that to improve the question before posting elsewhere (e.g., mention suggestions you got and what you did with those suggestions or why they don't solve your question, if they are relevant/helpful).  Instead of deleting and posting elsewhere, it is also possible to flag for moderator attention and ask them to migrate the question.

Comment: Simple does not mean easy. E.g. solve $y^y=x$ for $y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We shall asymptotically solve $\color{blue}{ f(2n) = f(n)·\log(f(n))·2^c }$ for any $c∈ℝ$ as $n → ∞$ (where $\log = \log_2$).
$
\def\lfrac#1#2{{\large\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$

~ ~ ~

Note that $\log\log(2n) = \log(\log(n)+1)$ $= \log\log(n)+\lfrac{r}{\log(n)}+\cdots$ where $r = \lfrac1{\ln(2)}$. (Omitted terms are asymptotically smaller.)

And $\log\log\log(2n) = \log\big(\log\log(n)+\lfrac{r}{\log(n)}+\cdots\big)$ $= \log\log\log(n)+\lfrac{r^2}{\log(n)·\log\log(n)}+\cdots$.

Let $g$ be a function such that $f(n) = 2^{\log(n)·\log\log(n)+g(n)}$. We shall take for granted (I believe it can be proven with some effort) that $g(n) ≪ \log(n)·\log\log(n)$.

Then $f(2n) = 2^{\log(2n)·\log\log(2n)+g(2n)}$

$= 2^{\log(2n)·\big(\log\log(n)+\lfrac{r}{\log(n)}+\cdots\big)+g(2n)}$

$= 2^{\log(2n)·\log\log(n)+g(2n)+r·\big(1+\lfrac1{\log(n)}\big)+\cdots}$.

And $f(n)·\log(f(n))·2^c$

$= 2^{\log(n)·\log\log(n)+g(n)+\log(\log(n)·\log\log(n)+g(n))+c}$

$= 2^{\log(n)·\log\log(n)+g(n)+\log(\log(n)·\log\log(n))+\lfrac{r·g(n)}{\log(n)·\log\log(n)}+c}$

$= 2^{\log(2n)·\log\log(n)+g(n)+\log\log\log(n)+c+\lfrac{r·g(n)}{\log(n)·\log\log(n)}}$.

Thus $g(2n)-g(n) = \log\log\log(n)+(c-r)−\lfrac{r}{\log(n)}+\lfrac{r·g(n)}{\log(n)·\log\log(n)}+\cdots$.

So $g(2^{k+1})-g(2^k) = \log\log(k)+(c-r)+\cdots$ as $k → ∞$.

Thus $g(2^k) = \sum_{i=2}^{k-1} \log\log(i) + k·(c-r) + \cdots$.

$ = k·\log\log(k) + k·(c-r) + \cdots$.

Thus $g(n) = \log(n)·\log\log\log(n)+\log(n)·(c-r)+\cdots$.

Therefore $\color{blue}{ f(n) = 2^{\log(n)·(\log\log(n)+\log\log\log(n)+(c-r)+\cdots)} }$.

~ ~ ~

To check, letting $f_1(n) = 2^{\log(n)·(\log\log(n)+\log\log\log(n)+(c-r))}$ we get:

$\log(f_1(2n))$

$= \log(2n)·(\log\log(2n)+\log\log\log(2n)+(c-r))$

$= (\log(n)+1)·\big(\log\log(n)+\log\log\log(n)+(c-r)+\frac{r}{\log(n)}+\cdots\big)$

$\log(f_1(n)·\log(f_1(n))·2^c)$

$= \log(n)·(\log\log(n)+\log\log\log(n)+(c-r))+\log\log(n)+\log\log\log(n)+c+\cdots$.

So $\log(f_1(2n)) - \log(f_1(n)·\log(f_1(n))·2^c) = \frac{r}{\log(n)} + \cdots$, as expected.

~ ~ ~

It may be possible to get an exact asymptotic solution, since we just have to find some $h$ such that $f(n) ∈ 2^{\log(n)·\big(\log\log(n)+\log\log\log(n)+(c-r)+h(n)+O(\lfrac1{\log(n)})\big)}$, but I'm not sure it's worth the trouble.

Answer (score 3):

Let us attempt to solve the easier recurrence $T(2n) = T(n) \log T(n)$. Define $S(m) = \log T(2^m)$. Then $S(m+1) = S(m) + \log S(m)$. Let us heuristically convert this into a differential equation: $S' = \log S$. The solution to this equation is $S = \mathrm{li}^{-1} + C$, where $\mathrm{li}$ is the [logarithmic integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogarithmicIntegral.html). Roughly speaking, $\mathrm{li}(x) \approx x/\log x$, and so $\mathrm{li}^{-1}(x) \approx x\log x$. This heuristic implies that $S(m) \approx m \log m$, and so $T(n) \approx \exp \Theta(\log n \log \log n)$. Of course, at this point this is just an educated guess.

As a sanity check, suppose that $T(n) = \exp (\log n \log \log n)$, where all logarithms are base 2. Then
$$
\begin{align*}
T(n) \log T(n) &= \exp (\log n \log \log n) \log n \log \log n \\ &=
\exp (\log n \log \log n + \log \log n + \log \log \log n) \\ &=
\exp (\log (2n) \log \log n + \log \log \log n).
\end{align*}
$$
This is quite similar to $T(2n) = \exp (\log (2n) \log \log (2n))$ (though not the same).

Comment: This is a good heuristic way of solving recurrences and $\exp(\log \cdot \log\log)$ is close. I was hoping for an exact solution but I will accept this answer if no exact solution is found.

Comment: See my answer for a much more precise asymptotic analysis. =)